# Multiple arrays inside array, new div for each array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Okay so I have multiple arrays inside an array. For each array inside the array I want the inner array to to be echoed in a new div. I'm completely lost on how to do this

Also, it should not make a div if the array is empty.

This is the code I'm using to var_dump the following output:

[image: code]

This is the output:
[image: screenshot]

I've read through php array documentation and searched on stackoverflow, I can't seem to find an answer so please help. Thanks!

Comment: $game_video is an object if you want to work on it as an array look at get_object_vars function

Comment: What if you just drop the `[]` in the foreach in your comment? So: `foreach($game_video as $a)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($video_by_game as $game_video)
    if(count($game_video)) {
        echo '<div>';
        foreach($game_video as $game)
           echo $game->title.'<br />';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: You have syntax error missing a closing bracket in your first if ;)

Comment: haha thanks - Stack Overflow should add syntax check before posting comment;)

Comment: Can't believe it was so obvious, I feel stupid now. Thanks for the answer! Had to fix a syntax error though `echo $game->title.'<br />';`. I'll accept the answer when it lets me! CHeers!

Answer (score 1):

Do not do a foreach $game_video[], do foreach $game_video.

```
foreach($videos_by_game as $game_video) {
    foreach($game_video as $gv) {
        // do your output
    }
}
```

The $game_video is already an array. By doing $game_video[], you are trying to iterate on its first element

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($video_by_game as $videos): // foreach game ?>
<?php    foreach($videos as $video): // foreach video of the game ?>
<?php      if (empty($video)) continue; // if no videos -/> skip ?>
 <div>
   Title: <?php echo $video->title ?> <br>
   Added by: <?php echo $video->added_by ?> <br>
 </div>
<?php    endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk function to process each item of $game_video array:

```
if (!empty($game_video)) {
    echo "<div>";
    array_walk($game_video, function($item,$key){ 
                               echo "The necessary output";
                            });
    echo "</div>";
}
```